# Can the 2011 SP1 & 2012 UI Session Preview web service and broker DB support multiple sites?

Tags: experience-manager

I'm adding a 2nd site to a running 2011 SP1 with the 2012 UI (new SiteEdit).

The new site will be physically separate to the existing one, so will have different publication targets, http_upload service and broker databases for the 'live' site; but I'm not totally clear on setting up the internal 2012 UI (new SiteEdit) in page editing. components for it.

Can I use the same Session Preview Webservice and preview broker database - or do I need to duplicate these components for the new site?

Answer (score 5):

It shouldn't be an issue as long as you have different publication targets and of course different publications.

You can share the same Content Delivery Web Serivce since it is stateless, it will just perform the fast track publishing processing the POST data.

The database can be the same, there are 2 tables that make that possible in the data model, `Preview_Sesions` and `Preview_Publication_Mappings`. Actually what you will see in the database are faked publication ids (sequential numbers) so we ensure the items are unique, then the API will map them correctly using the Preview_Publication_Mappings table.

Comment: Thanks very much Eric! I'll have a go and let you know :-)

Comment: Should also work with the same publication target, you just need to add the URL of your staging site(s) to the session preview settings